# Use PKCS#11 token to connect to a sshd server from inside Java program

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, pkcs#11

Main question:

Is there any way to connect to a sshd server from inside a Java program when the server enforces public-key authentication mechanism and the key-pair should be stored in PKCS#11 tokens?

Explanation:

I can connect to the server from the console using the following command:

```
ssh -I myPkcs11TokenLib.so myUserName@myHostName
```

So, It seems that everything configured correctly on sshd.

I was also able to establish the connection inside Java program using `jsch` when the server was configured to use password based authentication. Sample code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session sshSession = jsch.getSession("myUserName", "myHostName", 22);
sshSession.setPassword("myPass");
sshSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
sshSession.connect(5000);
```

Moreover, I know that `jsch` has the method `public void addIdentity(String name, byte[] prvkey, byte[] pubkey, byte[] passphrase)` for public-key authentication.

However, I do NOT know **how can I read the key-pair from my PKCS#11 token and convert it to an appropriate format** that is acceptable to the above mentioned method.

Even if I retrieve private key from token and appropriately pass it to `addIdentity` method, it is not exactly what is intended in token-based authentication. As far as I know, `ssh -I` command does not extract the private key from token. Instead, it redirects the public cryptographic functions (e.g. RSA sign) to the token. In contrast, `addIdentity` method needs the plain private key. Thus, it will not be secure enough in some situations. (The private key leaks into the RAM in plain!)

In short, I want to know if there is a way to **simulate `ssh -I` in Java program** in order to establish a connection to a sshd server?